# How to exclude a folder and not its children from SVN Update in Tortoise SVN

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am working on a shared project which is put in SVN. The directory structure of the project is as follows:

ParentDir

    - Child_Dir_1

           + GrandChild_Dir_1

           + GrandChild_Dir_2

       - Child_Dir_2

Child_Dir_1 contains configuration files (Eclipse's .LAUNCH files), and people put all sorts of file in this folder.

So each time I update my source code (by right clicking on ParentDir and picking Update), I got a lot of configurations that I don't really need, and I have to delete them manually.

I still need to have the children of Child_Dir_1 (which are GrandChild_Dir_1 and GrandChild_Dir_2) to be updated.

I have tried to go to set the "ignore" property of the of Child_Dir_1 to exclude *.LAUNCH files, but each time I update the source code, the ones that I manually deleted are restored to Child_Dir_1.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using TortoiseSVN:

Go into `Child_Dir_1`, select `GrandChild_Dir_1 and GrandChild_Dir_2` and right click, TortoiseSVN -> Update.

That will update only those two folders.

Ignore is so that you can "ignore" ( from commit, status etc.) untracked files, files that are not checked in.

Comment: I think that on commit Tortoise may complain about Child_Dir_1 not being up-to-date, and will abort the commit.

Comment: @Dialecticus It should not affect. Only a file being committed should be updated.

Comment: Your solution requires some manual work, and may not work in this case because there are actually many folders under ParentDir (not 2 as in my example). I usually update my project by right clicking on ParentDir and select "Update" (with Tortoise SVN). I was looking for a way that I can still do the Update in "one shot" and skip Child_Dir_1. Thanks

Comment: @Tom - Sorry, is selecting multiple folders in Windows Explorer ( drag and select? Shift + down arrow??) significant manual work?

Comment: The folder structure is much more complicated than I described in my original posting. Navigating thru a few levels and selecting the right folders several times a day is indeed significant work to me :) Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

It could be that manojlds' answer is the solution for you, but I have doubts. The problem here is that those files are really part of the project. They are kind of unavoidable, and must be in sync with the rest of working copy.

Option 1 (best): Remove all configuration files form repository, or better yet have in repository only configuration template files (with, say, $ as first character in file names). Each user could copy those template files to true configuration files and change them accordingly. Configuration files should not ever be committed. Only template files should, but updating template files will not mess with current configuration files of any user.

Option 2 (second best): Ignore those configuration files. Use your own files for your own configuration, with names that don't clash with existing. You may even add your files to SVN, but you may just as well not add them. Does not matter, as long as you don't need your configuration on another machine.

Option 3: Use ignore-on-commit group. Use those configuration files that already exist. Change them to your likings, but don't ever commit them. To ensure that you don't commit them by accident flag them as non-committable (go to commit window, select all non-committable files, right click > Move to changelist > ignore-on-commit). The problem with this is your files are not protected from other users' updates, but may actually be a good thing.

Option 4: Chop the folder out (a horrible hack). Remove Child_Dir_1 from working copy (Right click on it > Update to revision > set Working depth to Exclude). Save the folder elsewhere first, because it will disappear. After that create it again, inside it checkout all subfolders (GrandChild_Dir_1 and GrandChild_Dir_2), and copy your configuration files. Now you have complete control over folder's contents, but update and commit become more complicated.

Edit: There is option 5 in theory, but I doubt it can be implemented successfully. You can try: Use [NTFS hard links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link). Copy the whole tree with all files as hard links to existing files, except .svn folders and their contents. Original directory is used for SVN operations update, commit, add and delete, and new directory is used for editing files. From new directory delete all the files you don't need, and insert all the files you do need that are not the part of SVN. The problem here is minor extra work when deleting files from and adding them to SVN.

Comment: Option 1 is not an option in my case. Option 2 also doesn't work as in Eclipse, I'd see dozens of run configurations filling up the screen and that'd be very annoying. Option 3: my configuration files have different names so no updates will override mine. I will never commit anything in this folder as well. Option 4 doesn't work for me because revamping the folder structure is not an option as well (it's a shared project and I am just a regular member). Thanks